# Unstable results when I train a CNN

Tags: convolutional-neural-network

I'm currently training a CNN to do a binary classification.
I'm getting fairly good results, but unfortunately the training is very unstable.
Just by changing the seed the relative error changes by 20-30%.

What can be the cause of this and how can I prevent it?

Other info:

- The amount of data is rather small.
- I'm starting from imagenet snapshot.

Comment: Are you using tensorflow? You may make a new session for each for. It was one of my main issues :)

Answer (score 1):

- Understand a data
- Find the most suitable metrics
- handle missing values
- normalize, scale etc your variables
- feature selecting
- use cross validation(kfold for example)
- try oversampling or undersampling
- trying other models

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to read the following:

http://karpathy.github.io/2019/04/25/recipe/